# Consolidate and parse 4 databases into one

Tags: c#, database, dataset, ms-access-2010, visual-studio-express

In order to better define my problem I'll explain in steps:

- I need to consolidate selected data from 4 databases into one.
- Each database logs data obtained from an industrial system (sensors and switches, mainly).
- DBs are in .accdb format with encryption
- Each source database has 3 columns:

  - timestamp (datetime format)
  - point_id (Variable name - text format)
  - _VAL (Variable value - text format in two DBs, byte in the other two DBs)
- Variable value is logged in one row every time it changes (1-second resolution), and all variables are logged once every 15 minutes (to get a snapshot of the system every so often). Example:

  - 1/9/2014 1:35:54 AM - Tank_Volume - 5,763
  - 1/9/2014 1:35:54 AM - Line_Pressure - 14,325
  - 1/9/2014 1:35:55 AM - Tank_Volume - 5,121
  - 1/9/2014 1:35:56 AM - Tank_Volume - 4,911
- I'm logging a total of 511 variables
- The output DB requirements are:

  - Each row must contain one second of data for all variables, sequentially and without skipping seconds
  - Each variable must have its own column (511 variables + 1 for timestamp), preferably with an appropriate format to save on space (output DB must be sent by e-mail)
  - If the variable value hasn't changed for the given second, it can take the last logged value for that variable
  - It must contain data only for a selected period of time (e.g.: from 1/8/2014 1:30:00 AM to 1/8/2014 3:45:00 AM) - I have the fields for selection in the UI
  - The user must be prompted to save this consolidated DB
  - The DB should be optimized in order to reduce its size after all data is copied to it

I know it's not too complex, but I want an opinion on the best way to deal with all this data. The source databases might have more than 1 GB each (many many days of log). I'll usually get only 3~4 hours of data from them into the output DB, but it'll be 14000+ rows (one per second) with 512 cols, parsed cell by cell...I imagine that's a lot to process, right?

My idea is to:

1. Establish connection with the 4 source DBs (they are located in one fixed directory)
2. Select the data to be extracted from each DB (based on the UI Start and End datetime fields) and place it in one large DataTable (SourceData)
3. Once SourceData is populated, close connection with the source DBs
4. Create 3 output DataTables (OutputData) with an algorithm that parses each line from SourceData on a second-by-second basis and place it in the right row/column (based in the timestamp and point_id source columns) - and if there's no data for any given point in time, repeat the value from the previous second
5. Open connection to an output DB (supposedly empty), or create one, if possible
6. Check if there's any table there and drop them, if true
7. Create 3 tables to contain all cols (timestamp being the primary for all 3 tables)
8. Populate these tables with the data from OutputData
9. Optimize the tables to reduce size
10. Save the DB to a backup folder and prompt the user to save the DB in another place as well, and displaying the final file size
11. Clear both the SourceData and DataTable to clear RAM usage

Is there a more **efficient/easy** way to achieve my goal? At first I was going for immediate read/write to/from the DBs, but I figured working with variables inside the executable would be a lot faster that file I/O...
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Have you written this yet? It is easier to optimize a process _after_ you have the code base made.

Comment: *"Create a DATA table with all 512 columns"*  An Access table can include up to 255 fields, but no more.

Comment: @gunr2171 I've just created the DB connection method and some confirmation dialogs. I realize it's better to improve a code once it has a base, but I'm on a very tight schedule, don't know if I'll have time to improve code, only write it as improved as possible and implement. The idea I need is regarding the most efficient and simple way to achieve this, with the minimum coding possible...
Thanks!

Comment: @HansUp I forgot to look into that limit, thanks a lot! I guess I'll have to split the data into 3 tables, no problem there...I'll edit the question to correct this.